# NGXS - Testing Lazy Selectors failure

Tags: javascript, angular, ngxs

we are using ngxs and we do have some lazy selectors defined in separated files from the state definition

```
export class SectionSelectors {

  @Selector([CatalogState])
  static ById(state: CatalogModel) {
    return function getSectionById(id: number): Section {
      const selectedSection: Section = state.sections[id];
      return selectedSection;
    };
  }
}
```

And we have test cases like

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Section } from '@miq-catalog/catalog';
import { NgxsModule, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { CatalogModel, CatalogState } from './catalog.state';
import { SectionSelectors } from './section.selectors';

describe('SectionSelectors', () => {

  it('should select the section by id', () => {
    const one: Section = { sectionId: 1, title: '', columns: [] };
    const two: Section = { sectionId: 2, title: '', columns: [] };
    const state: CatalogModel = {
      catalog: [],
      sections: { 1: one, 2: two },
      columns: {},
      catalogLoaded: true,
    };

    const selectionFunction = SectionSelectors.ById(state);

    const result = selectionFunction(1);
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    expect(result).toBe(one);
    expect(result.sectionId).toBe(1);

    const result2 = selectionFunction(2);
    expect(result2).toBeDefined();
    expect(result2).toBe(two);
    expect(result2.sectionId).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

We are passing the state to the selector however we are getting the next error

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CatalogState' before initialization
  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CatalogState' before initialization
```

I noticed that if I move these selector to the CatalogState (where the @State definition is) the problem is fixed. But this is forcing us to put all selectors there and we think it's good to have them scoped on their own related files so we don't "pollute" with mixed selectors.

Is there a way we can fix the test case? Does someone already faced this Lazy Selector testing before?

As complementary info this is how our State looks like

```
@State({
  name: 'Catalog',
  defaults: {
    catalogLoaded: false,
    columns: {},
    sections: {},
    catalog: [],
  },
})
export class CatalogState {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  @Action(RetrieveCatalogInfo)
  @Action(ChangeColumnConfig)
  @Action(ClearCatalog)
  public executeAction(ctx: StateContext<CatalogModel>, params: ExecutableAction<CatalogModel>) {
    return params.execute({ ctx, store: this.store });
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of NGXS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem with the latest version of NGXS (since v3.6.1).