# How to test NGXS selectors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-runner, ngxs

Hi I am using NGXS state managment library in my App and I have selector like below and everything is working fine but when I am testing my app I have got error like below. PrintItemsState is lazy loadad. What I noticed problem is that im passing PrintItemsState as argument here.

```
@Selector([PrintItemsState])
```

but i have no clue how to fix it. I will be graceful for any suggestions.

[image]

**print-items.selectors.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class PrintItemsSelectors { 
...

  @Selector([PrintItemsState])
  static filter(state: PrintItemsStateModel): KeyValue<string, string>[] {
    const filters = state.fabricPage.page.Filter;
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(state.fabricPage.page.Filter);
    const activeFilters = [];
    filterKeys.forEach((key) => {
      if (filters[key]) {
        activeFilters.push({key: [key], value: filters[key]});
      }
    });
    return activeFilters;
  }

...
}
```

**print-items.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PrintItemsListComponent,
    FabricTableComponent,
    SummaryTableComponent,
    RollCodeDialogComponent,
    CommentDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    PrintItemsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxsModule.forFeature([PrintItemsState])
  ],
  providers: [
    PrintItemsHttpService
  ]
})
export class PrintItemsModule {
}
```

Comment: Are you calling forRoot in your test module? Also if you think that injecting the state like that is the issue change the code use store instead or move this inside of the state as a memo

Comment: @misha130 thanks for your answer. I moved it inside state as a memo and it is working but now inisde state I have mixed actions and selectors. I wold have to avoid situation like this and have separate file for selectors. I am importing NgxsModule.forRoot(),in my *.spec files but not in all of them. So maybe aI should try to add NgxsModule.forRoot(), to all spec files?

Comment: So I tried to add NgxsModule.forRoot() to all of *.spec.ts files but with no success. It is the same as before. What is weird I have others selectors defined in exactly tha same way as PrintItemsSelectors but only PrintItemsSelectors is causing error.

Comment: Try opening an issue in their github, it seems odd that as a memo it works and in an injectable it doesn't. Though looking in their docs for injecting selectors I dont see the methods are supposed to be static

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly I still havent`t solved my problem. I have posted question on their github but without answer. I found [simillar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507225/ngxs-testing-lazy-selectors-failure) but I am using NGXS 3.7.2 so it shouldnt be a case. Temporary solution is that I moved selectors inside state class.